# Machine coding an Arduino/Atmel328 over a serial line from a tethered (host) PC

Tags: arduino, function-pointers, shared-memory, avr, atmel

I'm trying to write a program for the *AVR Atmel 328 chip* that will allow me to send machine code instructions to the chip over a serial line, run/execute them on the chip, and interrogate the results by reading chip memory and sending the contents back over the serial line.  This is the genesis of the idea: [3-instruction Forth by Frank Sergeant](http://pygmy.utoh.org/3ins4th.html).

The remote-store and remote-fetch instructions appear to be working fine, but **I've not been able to get the remote-call instruction (`XCALL()` function) to work.** The approach I've taken is to coerce a 16-bit address into a subroutine by casting it as a function pointer.

Below is the code that is running on the Arduino Nano (compiled in the Arduino IDE and uploaded using the USB cable via the bootloader)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  (I can add diassembled code, my remote instructions etc, if that helps).

Thanks in advance!

```
// Remote serial development platform for machine coding ArduinoNano/ATmel328, AKE, Jun 9, 2020

// global variables
unsigned char byt;                  // command token from host
unsigned char mem[255];             // memory window under programmatic control
unsigned char dat;                  // data byte from host
unsigned char adr_lo;               // address from host, low byte first
unsigned char adr_hi;           
unsigned short adr;                 // combined 16-bit address
typedef void (*GeneralFunction)();  // template to call memory address (as a subroutine)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);              // Turn UART serial protocol ON for comms with host PC
  Serial.write(0xFF);              // magic number to verify transmission
  Serial.write(0xFE);
  Serial.write((int) mem);         // Informs you of the writeable address space available (LSB, MSB) for tethered memory access
  Serial.write((int) mem>>8);      
}

char get_byte(void) {
    while (!(Serial.available()>0)) { delay(50); }
    return Serial.read();
}
short get_adr(void) {
    adr_lo=get_byte();
    adr_hi=get_byte();
    return ( (short)adr_hi<<8 )   |   (short)adr_lo;
}
void xstore() {             // Instruction 1 = xstore(data,adr_lo,adr_hi).  Store byte from host at indicated address in target.
    dat=get_byte();
    adr=get_adr();
    *(char *)adr=dat;
}
void xfetch() {             //  Instruction 2 = xfetch(adr_lo,adr_hi).  Read byte from target memory and return to host.
        adr=get_adr();
        dat=*(char *)adr;
        Serial.write(dat);
}
void xcall() {              //  Instruction 3 = xcall(adr_lo,adr_hi).  Execute subroutine in target memory from indicated address.
                            //  WARNING!  User must have stored RET instruction to send control back to serial monitor.
        adr=get_adr();
        GeneralFunction fGf=adr;
        fGf();
}

void loop() {
    byt = get_byte();               // user specified instruction token (1,2,3)
    if(byt == 0x01 )      { xstore(); } 
    else if (byt == 0x02) { xfetch(); } 
    else if (byt == 0x3 ) { xcall(); } // else ignore any other serial inputs
}
```

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/36980

Comment: @gre_gor: thanks, [interesting link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36980/executing-machine-code-at-runtime-uno)  - though in the above we are attempting to use the bootloaded code itself to switch to the injected machine code at runtime.  What is needed is how to get a generic header/hook/container the code can run, and into which machine code can be injected dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us the exact name of your chip but I suspect you are using the ATmega328P.

The ATmega328P cannot execute instructions from RAM.  You will need to figure out how to write the code to flash before you can execute it.  You might want to use a bootloader like [Optiboot](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot) to write the program to flash, or you could study Optiboot to see how it works.  Note that the flash is only rated for a limited number of erase/write cycles (typically 10000).

Also, your C++ syntax is wrong.  To call a function, you always need to use parentheses.  So you would write `fGf()`. instead of just `fGf`.

Comment: Aha! so the reason why xstore() and xfetch() worked was because I was injected code into the mem[255] array, which was created in RAM, and hence unavailable to the Program Counter.  This clears up why the xcall did not compile and the observation that the disassembled ELF file seemed to skip over the fGf() call.  Re syntax, this is intended to be straight C  (yes I used the // comment style as it's more convenient than /* */ and the Arduino compiler allows it).  Yes it is ATmega328 (first line of the question).   Thanks much - accepting your answer!

Comment: Also sharing this [neat set of articles](https://arduino-forth.com/article) on [FlashForth for Arduino](https://arduino-forth.com/article/FORTH_FlashForth_installation_installerFlashForth) boards/ATmega328.  Articles by Marc Petremann (veteran Forth coder).  Thanks to [@jsotola](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/76341/56616) for the link!

Comment: Whether we are talking about C or C++, you need parentheses to call a function.

Comment: Thanks @David Grayson --- fixed the code in the question.